# Relative file path

Tags: ajax, path

This is something I am very puzzled, and hope I can explain it well here.

I have a js file that is located in c:/rootFolder/common/js/jsfile.js. In this file I use an AJAX function that calls a file at the rootFolder, called update.aspx, as follows:

```
...
...
httprequest.open("GET", "update.aspx", true);
...
```

I have many files in many levels of folders that will call this function. If a file c:/rootFolder/abc/abc.aspx calls this function, then the above AJAX would be:

```
httprequest.open("GET", "../update.aspx", true);
```

So I need a way so that I can make the path relative easier to call the function from any aspx. I am using cookieless session for this project as well, therefore the URL will be like

http: //localhost/S(abssadasdadd...

Comment: Why can't you use absolute paths by prefixing your request with '/'? Like, `httprequest.open("GET", "/update.aspx", true);`

Comment: tried that, but doesn't work.

Comment: What happens when you try that?

Answer (score 0):

After a while searching I came to suspect that there should be something that the html or server might be looking as the base. Thus I solved the problem by adding a base tag at the top of the page, specifically in the HEAD tags.

```
<base href="www.abc.com" />
```

However, I am using cookieless sessions which placed the session id in the URL. How would I add that on to the base (otherwise, it would still not work)? The simple answer in the following:

```
string baseurl=  "http://" + servername + "/(S(" + HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID + "))";
```

If you have a Master file, you can place the base in the head:

```
<base href="<%=baseurl%>" />
```

If these in place, you will call your css and js files easily:

```
<link type="text/css" href="common/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="common/js/jscript.js"></script>
```